# I am creating a recent posts widgets for practice but I need help correctly making it so admin can adjust the category displayed

Tags: widget, wordpress

So like I said in the title, I am creating a recent posts widget for practice. It includes different features and the one that I am having problems with it is allowing admin to choose the category they want to display. I currently have it set up so that in the form it has a text field in which the admin can input the category manually but I need it to be such that it has a drop down menu that already has the category there, so the admin can just select it. I am not sure how to do this at all so if I could get some help that would be great. Sorry if I am being vague, I am new to this. I am posting my code below.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: News Recent Posts Widget
Plugin URI: 
Description: A recent post widget with extra functions that allow admin to make changes to certain values
Author: Kevin Ullyott
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://modmacro.com/
*/


class recentpost extends WP_Widget {

    public function __construct() {
    parent::WP_Widget(
    // or parent::__construct(
        false, 
        'Kevin - Recent Posts Widget',
        array(
            'description' => __('A recent post widget with extra functions that allow admin to make changes to certain values') 

        )
    );
    ;
}

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {


        extract( $args );

        $headline = $instance['headline'];
        $category = $instance['category'];
        $numberposts = $instance['numberposts'];
        $readmore = $instance['readmore'];


        echo $before_widget;

        echo $before_title;

        echo "<p class=\"headline\">$headline</p>";

        echo $after_title;

        $args = array( 'numberposts' => $numberposts, 'category_name' => $category );
        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
        foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        setup_postdata(get_post($recent['ID']));
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent['ID']) . '" title=" '.esc_attr(get_the_title($recent['ID'])).'" >' .   get_the_title($recent['ID']).'</a> ';
        echo get_the_time('F j, Y', $recent['ID']);
        the_excerpt();
}
wp_reset_postdata();


        echo $after_widget;


    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['headline'] = ( $new_instance['headline'] );
        $instance['category'] = ( $new_instance['category'] );
        $instance['numberposts'] = ( $new_instance['numberposts'] );
        $instance['readmore'] = ( $new_instance['readmore'] );
        return $instance;
    }


    public function form( $instance ) {

        $headline = $instance[ 'headline' ];
        $category = $instance[ 'category' ];
        $numberposts = $instance[ 'numberposts' ];
        $readmore = $instance[ 'readmore' ];

        ?>

<p>
  <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'headline' ); ?>">
    <?php _e( 'Headline:' ); ?>
  </label>
  <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'headline' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'headline' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $headline ); ?>" />
</p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'category' ); ?>">
  <?php _e( 'Category:' ); ?>
</label>
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'category' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'category' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $category ); ?>" />
</p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'numberposts' ); ?>">
  <?php _e( 'Number of posts:' ); ?>
</label>
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'numberposts' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'numberposts' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $numberposts ); ?>" />
</p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'readmore' ); ?>">
  <?php _e( 'Read More:' ); ?>
</label>
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'readmore' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'readmore' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $readmore ); ?>" />
</p>
<?php 
    }
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("recentpost");') );


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function wp_dropdown_categories will bring in the categories but adding the function alone wont save or retrieve the selected category.  You'll need to add the `name` `selected` and `id` arguments.  This should work I think:

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories(array('name' => $this->get_field_name('category'), 'selected' => $category, 'id' => $this->get_field_id('category'), 'class' => 'widefat')); ?>
```

I added class `widefat` as well but its only for presentation.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I am not sure how to add the name, selected, and id arguments. Hey would I do that?

Comment: The answer is in my repsonse above.  You should be able to replace your input the code i posted about and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The function wp_dropdown_categories displays a dropdown menu that pulls in all of the categories used in the site.  Here is the documentation on it: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories

So you can replace

get_field_id( 'category' ); ?>" name="get_field_name( 'category' ); ?>" type="text" value="" />

with a call to the wp_dropdown_categories function.